Unzipping MDF4 files and combining them into 1
I am trying unzip a collection of mdf4 files, combine them into 1 mdf4 file and save it. I am getting the following error:
Invalid argument at position 2. Value must be one of the following types: 'timetable'
Any help would be appreciated!
Here is the code:
% Open file selection dialog to choose MDF files
[fileNames, folderPath] = uigetfile('*.mdf;*.zip', 'Select MDF or ZIP files', 'MultiSelect', 'on');

if ~ischar(fileNames) % Check if any file is selected
    combinedData = struct(); % Initialize an empty structure to store combined data
   
    for i = 1:numel(fileNames)
        filePath = fullfile(folderPath, fileNames{i});
       
        % Check if the file is a ZIP archive
        if endsWith(filePath, '.zip')
            % Unzip the archive to a temporary folder
            tempFolder = tempname;
            unzip(filePath, tempFolder);
           
            % Find the MDF file(s) in the temporary folder
            mdfFiles = dir(fullfile(tempFolder, '*.mdf'));
           
            for j = 1:numel(mdfFiles)
                mdfFilePath = fullfile(tempFolder, mdfFiles(j).name);
                data = mdfimport(mdfFilePath);
               
                % Merge the data into the combined structure
                fieldNames = fieldnames(data);
                for k = 1:numel(fieldNames)
                    fieldName = fieldNames{k};
                    if isfield(combinedData, fieldName)
                        combinedData.(fieldName) = [combinedData.(fieldName), data.(fieldName)];
                    else
                        combinedData.(fieldName) = data.(fieldName);
                    end
                end
            end
           
            % Clean up the temporary folder
            rmdir(tempFolder, 's');
        else
            % Import the MDF file directly
            data = mdfimport(filePath);
           
            % Merge the data into the combined structure
            fieldNames = fieldnames(data);
            for k = 1:numel(fieldNames)
                fieldName = fieldNames{k};
                if isfield(combinedData, fieldName)
                    combinedData.(fieldName) = [combinedData.(fieldName), data.(fieldName)];
                else
                    combinedData.(fieldName) = data.(fieldName);
                end
            end
        end
    end
   
    % Save the combined data to a new MDF file
    [fileName, folderPath] = uiputfile('*.mdf', 'Save Combined MDF File');
    if fileName ~= 0 % Check if a file name is provided
        outputFilePath = fullfile(folderPath, fileName);
        mdfWrite(outputFilePath, combinedData);
        msgbox('MDF files combined successfully!', 'Success');
    end
end

1 Output file generated and saved in location with all mdf4 data

Which line of your code gives rise to the error?
